# How to submit a SGE job calling my python script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, job-scheduling

So, I want to run a python script in a remote machine. However, in the manual of the server, they say this:

> You need to create this script and save it.

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -V ## pass all environment variables to the job, VERY IMPORTANT
#$ -N run_something ## job name
#$ -S /bin/bash ## shell where it will run this job
#$ -j y ## join error output to normal output
#$ -cwd ## Execute the job from the current working directory
#$ -q lowmemory.q ## queue name
uptime > myUptime.${JOB_ID}.txt
echo $HOSTNAME >> myUptime.${JOB_ID}.txt
```

> So if this script was called blast_AE004437.sh we could run the following to make all of those steps happen.

```
qsub my_script.sh
```

So, I'm assuming that I need to create a .sh file to run this and add all this commands to my original script. Is that it? Because I'm doing that and nothing happens. After all this commands I also add "python2.7" to load python. What I'm doing wrong? By the way, the output will come out in the same file or do I need to download a different file?

Comment: If you have a python file named `my_script.py` on a remote machine that has python installed, you should be able to run `python my_script.py` from the commandline to execute the script. If this is not the answer you were looking for, some clarification would help.

Comment: Well, they ask us not to do that because that will run the script in the head node which can have implications for the usage of the server for other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you listed is the beginning of a SGE run script
which is called by the job scheduler. `qsub` submits it to the scheduling
system. As soon as there is a free slot on a cluster machine, the
run script is called there.

I suggest you to call your own script in this file.

```
...
echo $HOSTNAME >> myUptime.${JOB_ID}.txt

cd /directory/of/your/script                         # change directory  
python2.7 your_script.py arg1 arg2 ... >> output.${JOB_ID}.log  # call your script
```

Often you also need to set the $PATH variable and $PYTHONPATH variable manually
before you can call python.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new at this whole thing of using servers.
So, you mean that I should just run all of these commands in my terminal window, is that it?
And what do you mean by "arg1 arg2"?

Comment: No, this are the lines which you need to copy into the submission script (`my_script.sh`) which then calls your python script on the remote machines. `arg1` and `arg2` are just examples if you want to provide command lines arguments to your script (you can leave them out if you do not need them). The output of your script to stdout (`print` command in python) is written to the output.JOBID.log file.

Comment: Read e.g. http://bioinformatics.mdc-berlin.de/intro2UnixandSGE/sun_grid_engine_for_beginners/quickstart_and_basics.html for some introduction to the system.